# How can I have same page destination using hero

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a flutter app. It is an app that can create containers. Then, when you press on those containers, it will open up a page. So, I tried to use hero with infinitely creatable containers. This is what I came up with:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainPage());

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Body(),
            ])));
  }
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final String open1 = 'open';

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List cards = List.generate(count, (int i) => RCard(count));

    return Expanded(
        child: Container(
            child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
                onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
                  overscroll.disallowGlow();
                },
                child: PageView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
                    pageSnapping: false,
                    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85),
                    itemCount: count,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      if (i == 0) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Page(
                                          open: open1,
                                        )),
                              );
                              count++;
                            },
                            child: Hero(
                                tag: open1,
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.015,
                                        right:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.015,
                                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                            0.08,
                                        bottom:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                                0.15),
                                    child: Material(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        elevation: 8.0,
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons.add,
                                                  size: 30.0,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                )
                                              ]),
                                        )))));
                      } else {
                        return cards[i];
                      }
                    }))));
  }
}

class RCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int count;

  RCard(this.count);

  @override
  RCardState createState() => RCardState();
}

class RCardState extends State<RCard> {
  int count;
  String open2;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    open2 = 'open$count';
    count = widget.count;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: open2,
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Page(
                        open: open2,
                      )),
            );
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15),
            child: Material(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 8.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15),
                )),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final String open;

  Page({this.open});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Hero(tag: open, child: Material()),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But, this code only works when I create 1 container. When I create 2 containers and press on it, it gives me a black screen. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that all you need to do is delete the list 'cards' and change the 'cards[i]' method to 'RCard(i)'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainPage());

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Body(),
            ])));
  }
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final String open1 = 'open';

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Expanded(
        child: Container(
            child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
                onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
                  overscroll.disallowGlow();
                },
                child: PageView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
                    pageSnapping: false,
                    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85),
                    itemCount: count,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      if (i == 0) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Page(
                                          open: open1,
                                        )),
                              );
                              count++;
                            },
                            child: Hero(
                                tag: open1,
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.015,
                                        right:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                0.015,
                                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                            0.08,
                                        bottom:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                                0.15),
                                    child: Material(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        elevation: 8.0,
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                Icon(
                                                  Icons.add,
                                                  size: 30.0,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                )
                                              ]),
                                        )))));
                      } else {
                        return RCard(i);
                      }
                    }))));
  }
}

class RCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int count;

  RCard(this.count);

  @override
  RCardState createState() => RCardState();
}

class RCardState extends State<RCard> {
  int count;
  String open2;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    open2 = 'open$count';
    count = widget.count;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: open2,
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Page(
                        open: open2,
                      )),
            );
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15),
            child: Material(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 8.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15),
                )),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final String open;

  Page({this.open});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Hero(tag: open, child: Material()),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one Hero widget with the same tag value in a single class. If you want to have more than two Hero animation happen simultaneously, you have to give each Hero widgets different tag values.

Comment: nope heros with different tag names cannot be in the same tree no nested hero widgets at all per docs

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a unique `tag` value every time you create the `Hero`. The black screen error is most likely because two or more `Hero` elements are getting the same `tag` value.

For example, inside the `itemBuilder: (context, i)` you are getting the current index in the varible `i`. You can use this index to make the `tag` value unique.

```
child: Hero(
  tag: open1 + "$i",
  child: /*Rest of your code*/
)
```

You can do something similar to make sure the values for all the `tag` elements are unique. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: You need to make sure that for all the `Hero` widgets that get generated at run-time, their `tag` parameter value is not the same.
To make the value different for every new `Hero` widget, you can use something like the current index of the container generated, as I have mentioned in the above example.

Comment: Right now, my container widget is in a class called RCard and the main code is in my Body class. They both are in 2 different classes and I'm not sure how I can implement `tag: open1 + "$i",` in my code. Thanks for the help.